# Can you start a sentence with Such as?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, sentence-starts

"Even though I am not fortunate enough to visit the campus, reading about Notre Dame makes me feel at home with its attention to tradition, its history of innovations, academic research, and service efforts. **Such as** the university’s research efforts in the Computer Science and Engineering fields with projects such as Compucell, and organizations such as AMFIND and Education Bridge of Notre Dame."

To me, "Such as" seems out of place

Comment: “Such as, not, no,” said Yoda.

Comment: What exactly is the first "such as" supposed to refer to? It seems semantically incorrect/ inconsistent. Read over again.

Comment: It depends how you define 'sentence'. By the definition I use, this is a sentence fragment and not a sentence. Now, the more important question. _Is it incorrect_? While I've usually come out with comments such as 'Sentence fragments are not incorrect per se' and 'Used judiciously, they can generate punchiness, immediacy, tension', I'd knock a mark off for this example. I'd want at least 'Efforts/Endeavours such as the university's research into ...'.

Comment: Such as it is, dinner is served.

Comment: Or: "I think there are better options."  "Really? Such as what?" "***Such as*** trying the door before deciding to blow it up."

Comment: Yes, you can start a sentence with *such as*. No, the sentence in the question is not a great example of doing so. (But the whole passage is more semantically dubious than syntactically dubious—and the use of *such as* is not its only problem.)

Comment: You can certainly say: "Such causes as nuclear disarmament and world peace are the reasons I entered politics." You could omit the word "causes" if it was obvious and start a sentence "such as". But that's not the structure used in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

There is no predicate containing a finite verb, so that's not a sentence as many linguists commonly define the term.

Comment: See also my comment at OP.